# Kubernetes: Unable to mount a projected volume, no space on device when clearly there is

Tags: kubernetes, volumes, calico

I have a local k3d cluster in stalled on Mac (Big Sur 12) that I am attempting to install calico (their default manifest https://k3d.io/v5.3.0/usage/advanced/calico/).  In the logs for the calico-kube-controller pod, I get this:

Warning  FailedMount  44m                   kubelet            MountVolume.  SetUp failed for volume "kube-api-access-vfdd9" : write /var/lib/kubelet/pods/faa7d654-6424-4774-bc40-71de88c1d337/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-vfdd9/..2022_03_09_20_46_13.100604692/token: no space left on device

There is clearly plenty of space:

/var/lib/kubelet/pods/faa7d654-6424-4774-bc40-71de88c1d337/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected # df -h .

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/vda1        79G  7.7G   67G  11% /var/lib/kubelet

**Google searching has yielded nothing effective.**

Kubernetes version:  K8s Rev: v1.22.4+k3s1

Docker version:

Server: Docker Desktop 4.5.0 (74594)

Engine:
Version:          20.10.12

API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)

Go version:       go1.16.12

Git commit:       459d0df

Built:            Mon Dec 13 11:43:56 2021

OS/Arch:          linux/amd64

Experimental:     false

containerd: Version:          1.4.12

GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d

runc: Version:          1.0.2

GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2

docker-init:
Version:          0.19.0

GitCommit:        de40ad0

Any tips/docs/analysis would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

double check your container resources configuration for errors. Try to increase the values.

```
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: '1'
          memory: 500m
        requests:
          cpu: 50m
          memory: 100m
```

Mine started working when removed resources section completely. (Docker Desktop 4.3.2)

Comment: This worked for me!  I tripled the resources and that did not work, so, I eliminated them and that did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if there is a resourcequota configured.

```
kubectl get resourcequota
```

> somequota 14d pods: 0/2, requests.cpu: 0/1, requests.memory: 0/1024m
> limits.cpu: 0/4, limits.memory: 0/4096m

If you can are allowed to delete it then do and it will probably work

Comment: % kubectl get resourcequota --all-namespaces
No resources found